# What is cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am very new to cloud foundry and I am just picking up the things.

I am working with some other cloud providers like AWS, Azure etc in my day to day life.

Have read some docs provided by cloud foundry website. 
Not being in a development team, the following are my doubts, when cloud foundry says it is mostly used by dev team.

1. Is cloud foundry a public cloud model? or is it private?
2. Doesn't it has portal kind of things like AWS or Azure.? Couldn't find any.
3. Reading the docs, I followed like most useful for Dev team and they can interact with the system using cli. But then how does Cloud Foundry works, in the sense without having any portal how can we manage the resources.?
4. If you think I am incorrectly followed, can you please point me to the right direction.?

Comment: check this [article](http://elsoufy.blogspot.com/2015/02/installing-cloud-foundry-v2-locally-on.html) it may help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Cloud Foundry](http://cloudfoundry.org/) is an open source project that implements an approach to platform as a service (PaaS). The Cloud Foundry platform provides runtimes and services for applications so that you can focus on developing the code that goes in those runtimes.

Cloud Foundry is open in two main respects:

1. Anyone can become a provider by installing Cloud Foundry and making the platform available.
2. Code developed to deploy as runtimes in one Cloud Foundry install can likewise be deployed to others, so you're not locked into a particular provider.

Cloud Foundry buildpacks support a variety of programming languages so that you're not locked into one.  Vendors distinguish their offering in part by providing unique Cloud Foundry services that are available for the runtime applications to use, such as preinstalled databases, support for DevOps, etc.

You can download and install Cloud Foundry on your own hardware, but configuring and maintaining it to run properly can be daunting. An easier approach is to use a cloud hosting provider that already has the Cloud Foundry platform built in; then you don't have to install Cloud Foundry, you can just start using it. One such cloud provider is [IBM Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/), which (at present) provides platforms for applications that run in Cloud Foundry, Docker containers, and OpenStack virtual machines.

To answer your specific questions:

1. A provider can make their Cloud Foundry install publicly available or use it privately (or both).
2. The user can interface with any Cloud Foundry install via the Cloud Foundry CLI. Bluemix also provides a Web GUI for working with your runtimes and services.
3. Each provider optionally includes their own GUI.
4. You're pointed in the right direction to learn more about Cloud Foundry.